# calculating sum of events in neighboring units of analysis

Tags: r, tidyr, data-wrangling

I have a panel dataset that counts violent events per year in multiple districts on a map. I am interested in the number of violent events in neighboring districts as I assume violent events might spill over. Each district is identified via a field-Id called `fid` and each district has observations for the `year` 2004-2010. The variable `neighbor_id` captures the `fid` of all neighboring districts including the `fid` of the "investigated" district.

Here is a subset of my data, I am glad to receive any suggestions
(somehow  `dput()` added an L to each number in `fid` which does not appear in the regular data and should be removed):

```
structure(list(fid = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 
23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 
24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 
24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 
26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 
27L, 27L, 27L), year = c(2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 
2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2000, 2001, 
2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 
2013, 2014, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 
2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 
2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2000, 
2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 
2012, 2013, 2014, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 
2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 
2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 
2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 
2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 
2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2000, 2001, 2002, 
2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 
2014, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 
2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 
2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2000, 2001, 
2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 
2013, 2014, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 
2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 
2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2000, 
2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 
2012, 2013, 2014, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 
2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 
2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 
2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 
2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 
2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2000, 2001, 2002, 
2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 
2014, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 
2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 
2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2000, 2001, 
2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 
2013, 2014, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 
2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 
2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2000, 
2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009), violent_ev_sum = c(8, 
10, 37, 11, 7, 14, 13, 8, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 22, 24, 22, 34, 
15, 12, 6, 6, 5, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 32, 21, 67, 44, 56, 51, 25, 
5, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 15, 7, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 6, 2, 4, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 
7, 1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 5, 14, 5, 14, 16, 1, 3, 2, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 2, 4, 1, 5, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 36, 15, 10, 3, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 3, 6, 6, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 33, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 16, 3, 15, 
12, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 17, 7, 13, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2), neighbor_id = c("1, 3, 6, 9, 12, 221", 
"1, 3, 6, 9, 12, 221", "1, 3, 6, 9, 12, 221", "1, 3, 6, 9, 12, 221", 
"1, 3, 6, 9, 12, 221", "1, 3, 6, 9, 12, 221", "1, 3, 6, 9, 12, 221", 
"1, 3, 6, 9, 12, 221", "1, 3, 6, 9, 12, 221", "1, 3, 6, 9, 12, 221", 
"1, 3, 6, 9, 12, 221", "1, 3, 6, 9, 12, 221", "1, 3, 6, 9, 12, 221", 
"1, 3, 6, 9, 12, 221", "1, 3, 6, 9, 12, 221", "2, 3, 213", "2, 3, 213", 
"2, 3, 213", "2, 3, 213", "2, 3, 213", "2, 3, 213", "2, 3, 213", 
"2, 3, 213", "2, 3, 213", "2, 3, 213", "2, 3, 213", "2, 3, 213", 
"2, 3, 213", "2, 3, 213", "2, 3, 213", "3, 4, 12, 14, 213, 221", 
"3, 4, 12, 14, 213, 221", "3, 4, 12, 14, 213, 221", "3, 4, 12, 14, 213, 221", 
"3, 4, 12, 14, 213, 221", "3, 4, 12, 14, 213, 221", "3, 4, 12, 14, 213, 221", 
"3, 4, 12, 14, 213, 221", "3, 4, 12, 14, 213, 221", "3, 4, 12, 14, 213, 221", 
"3, 4, 12, 14, 213, 221", "3, 4, 12, 14, 213, 221", "3, 4, 12, 14, 213, 221", 
"3, 4, 12, 14, 213, 221", "3, 4, 12, 14, 213, 221", "4, 7, 11, 14, 16, 213", 
"4, 7, 11, 14, 16, 213", "4, 7, 11, 14, 16, 213", "4, 7, 11, 14, 16, 213", 
"4, 7, 11, 14, 16, 213", "4, 7, 11, 14, 16, 213", "4, 7, 11, 14, 16, 213", 
"4, 7, 11, 14, 16, 213", "4, 7, 11, 14, 16, 213", "4, 7, 11, 14, 16, 213", 
"4, 7, 11, 14, 16, 213", "4, 7, 11, 14, 16, 213", "4, 7, 11, 14, 16, 213", 
"4, 7, 11, 14, 16, 213", "4, 7, 11, 14, 16, 213", "5, 8, 13, 17", 
"5, 8, 13, 17", "5, 8, 13, 17", "5, 8, 13, 17", "5, 8, 13, 17", 
"5, 8, 13, 17", "5, 8, 13, 17", "5, 8, 13, 17", "5, 8, 13, 17", 
"5, 8, 13, 17", "5, 8, 13, 17", "5, 8, 13, 17", "5, 8, 13, 17", 
"5, 8, 13, 17", "5, 8, 13, 17", "6, 9, 221, 223", "6, 9, 221, 223", 
"6, 9, 221, 223", "6, 9, 221, 223", "6, 9, 221, 223", "6, 9, 221, 223", 
"6, 9, 221, 223", "6, 9, 221, 223", "6, 9, 221, 223", "6, 9, 221, 223", 
"6, 9, 221, 223", "6, 9, 221, 223", "6, 9, 221, 223", "6, 9, 221, 223", 
"6, 9, 221, 223", "7, 8, 9, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17", "7, 8, 9, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17", 
"7, 8, 9, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17", "7, 8, 9, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17", 
"7, 8, 9, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17", "7, 8, 9, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17", 
"7, 8, 9, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17", "7, 8, 9, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17", 
"7, 8, 9, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17", "7, 8, 9, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17", 
"7, 8, 9, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17", "7, 8, 9, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17", 
"7, 8, 9, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17", "7, 8, 9, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17", 
"7, 8, 9, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17", "8, 13, 15, 17", "8, 13, 15, 17", 
"8, 13, 15, 17", "8, 13, 15, 17", "8, 13, 15, 17", "8, 13, 15, 17", 
"8, 13, 15, 17", "8, 13, 15, 17", "8, 13, 15, 17", "8, 13, 15, 17", 
"8, 13, 15, 17", "8, 13, 15, 17", "8, 13, 15, 17", "8, 13, 15, 17", 
"8, 13, 15, 17", "9, 12, 15", "9, 12, 15", "9, 12, 15", "9, 12, 15", 
"9, 12, 15", "9, 12, 15", "9, 12, 15", "9, 12, 15", "9, 12, 15", 
"9, 12, 15", "9, 12, 15", "9, 12, 15", "9, 12, 15", "9, 12, 15", 
"9, 12, 15", "10, 13, 15", "10, 13, 15", "10, 13, 15", "10, 13, 15", 
"10, 13, 15", "10, 13, 15", "10, 13, 15", "10, 13, 15", "10, 13, 15", 
"10, 13, 15", "10, 13, 15", "10, 13, 15", "10, 13, 15", "10, 13, 15", 
"10, 13, 15", "11, 16, 213", "11, 16, 213", "11, 16, 213", "11, 16, 213", 
"11, 16, 213", "11, 16, 213", "11, 16, 213", "11, 16, 213", "11, 16, 213", 
"11, 16, 213", "11, 16, 213", "11, 16, 213", "11, 16, 213", "11, 16, 213", 
"11, 16, 213", "12, 14", "12, 14", "12, 14", "12, 14", "12, 14", 
"12, 14", "12, 14", "12, 14", "12, 14", "12, 14", "12, 14", "12, 14", 
"12, 14", "12, 14", "12, 14", "13, 15", "13, 15", "13, 15", "13, 15", 
"13, 15", "13, 15", "13, 15", "13, 15", "13, 15", "13, 15", "13, 15", 
"13, 15", "13, 15", "13, 15", "13, 15", "14", "14", "14", "14", 
"14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", 
"15", "15", "15", "15", "15", "15", "15", "15", "15", "15", "15", 
"15", "15", "15", "15", "16, 17", "16, 17", "16, 17", "16, 17", 
"16, 17", "16, 17", "16, 17", "16, 17", "16, 17", "16, 17", "16, 17", 
"16, 17", "16, 17", "16, 17", "16, 17", "17", "17", "17", "17", 
"17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", 
"18, 19, 22, 24, 180, 200, 242", "18, 19, 22, 24, 180, 200, 242", 
"18, 19, 22, 24, 180, 200, 242", "18, 19, 22, 24, 180, 200, 242", 
"18, 19, 22, 24, 180, 200, 242", "18, 19, 22, 24, 180, 200, 242", 
"18, 19, 22, 24, 180, 200, 242", "18, 19, 22, 24, 180, 200, 242", 
"18, 19, 22, 24, 180, 200, 242", "18, 19, 22, 24, 180, 200, 242", 
"18, 19, 22, 24, 180, 200, 242", "18, 19, 22, 24, 180, 200, 242", 
"18, 19, 22, 24, 180, 200, 242", "18, 19, 22, 24, 180, 200, 242", 
"18, 19, 22, 24, 180, 200, 242", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", 
"19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "20, 21, 22, 27, 53", 
"20, 21, 22, 27, 53", "20, 21, 22, 27, 53", "20, 21, 22, 27, 53", 
"20, 21, 22, 27, 53", "20, 21, 22, 27, 53", "20, 21, 22, 27, 53", 
"20, 21, 22, 27, 53", "20, 21, 22, 27, 53", "20, 21, 22, 27, 53", 
"20, 21, 22, 27, 53", "20, 21, 22, 27, 53", "20, 21, 22, 27, 53", 
"20, 21, 22, 27, 53", "20, 21, 22, 27, 53", "21, 22, 24, 26, 27, 241", 
"21, 22, 24, 26, 27, 241", "21, 22, 24, 26, 27, 241", "21, 22, 24, 26, 27, 241", 
"21, 22, 24, 26, 27, 241", "21, 22, 24, 26, 27, 241", "21, 22, 24, 26, 27, 241", 
"21, 22, 24, 26, 27, 241", "21, 22, 24, 26, 27, 241", "21, 22, 24, 26, 27, 241", 
"21, 22, 24, 26, 27, 241", "21, 22, 24, 26, 27, 241", "21, 22, 24, 26, 27, 241", 
"21, 22, 24, 26, 27, 241", "21, 22, 24, 26, 27, 241", "22, 23, 24, 200", 
"22, 23, 24, 200", "22, 23, 24, 200", "22, 23, 24, 200", "22, 23, 24, 200", 
"22, 23, 24, 200", "22, 23, 24, 200", "22, 23, 24, 200", "22, 23, 24, 200", 
"22, 23, 24, 200", "22, 23, 24, 200", "22, 23, 24, 200", "22, 23, 24, 200", 
"22, 23, 24, 200", "22, 23, 24, 200", "23", "23", "23", "23", 
"23", "23", "23", "23", "23", "23", "23", "23", "23", "23", "23", 
"24, 25, 241, 242", "24, 25, 241, 242", "24, 25, 241, 242", "24, 25, 241, 242", 
"24, 25, 241, 242", "24, 25, 241, 242", "24, 25, 241, 242", "24, 25, 241, 242", 
"24, 25, 241, 242", "24, 25, 241, 242", "24, 25, 241, 242", "24, 25, 241, 242", 
"24, 25, 241, 242", "24, 25, 241, 242", "24, 25, 241, 242", "25", 
"25", "25", "25", "25", "25", "25", "25", "25", "25", "25", "25", 
"25", "25", "25", "26", "26", "26", "26", "26", "26", "26", "26", 
"26", "26", "26", "26", "26", "26", "26", "27, 53, 57, 58, 240, 241", 
"27, 53, 57, 58, 240, 241", "27, 53, 57, 58, 240, 241", "27, 53, 57, 58, 240, 241", 
"27, 53, 57, 58, 240, 241", "27, 53, 57, 58, 240, 241", "27, 53, 57, 58, 240, 241", 
"27, 53, 57, 58, 240, 241", "27, 53, 57, 58, 240, 241", "27, 53, 57, 58, 240, 241"
)), row.names = c(NA, -400L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: do the neighbour_ids work both ways? In your sample data, `22` has `22, 23, 24, 200` as neighbours, but `23` only has `23` as neighbour? Should 23 not have 22 as neighbour as well?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! Most of the time it should work both ways but there can be exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for something like this

```
library(igraph)
library(data.table)
# set to data.table format
setDT(mydata)
# split mydata to a list, by year
L <- split(mydata, by = "year")
# loop over this List
final <- lapply(L, function(x) {
  # separate rows
  DT <- x[, strsplit(neighbor_id, ", ", fixed = TRUE), by = .(fid, year, violent_ev_sum, neighbor_id)]
  # get edges
  edges <- DT[!fid == V1, .(fid, V1)]
  # get vertices
  vert <- DT[!duplicated(V1), .(fid = as.numeric(V1))]
  vert[DT, value := i.violent_ev_sum, on = .(fid)]
  # create the igraph
  g <- graph_from_data_frame(edges, directed = FALSE, vertices = vert)
  # get the sum of the value of each neighbouring attribute
  data.table(fid = V(g)$name, 
             sum_neighbor = sapply( ego(g, 1 ,V(g), mode = 'all', mindist = 1), 
                                    function(i) sum(V(g)[i]$value, na.rm = TRUE)))
})
```

**what this code actually does**

```
# what does the above do step-by-step
# case: for the year 2000 (the first year)
DT <- L$`2000`
#    fid year violent_ev_sum            neighbor_id
# 1:   1 2000              8    1, 3, 6, 9, 12, 221
# 2:   2 2000             22              2, 3, 213
# 3:   3 2000             32 3, 4, 12, 14, 213, 221
# 4:   4 2000              6  4, 7, 11, 14, 16, 213
# 5:   5 2000              6           5, 8, 13, 17
# 6:   6 2000              0         6, 9, 221, 223
# ...

# split the neighbor_id to individual rows, crecateing anew colum 'V1' 
DT <- DT[, strsplit(neighbor_id, ", ", fixed = TRUE), by = .(fid, year, violent_ev_sum, neighbor_id)]
#    fid year violent_ev_sum            neighbor_id  V1
# 1:   1 2000              8    1, 3, 6, 9, 12, 221   1
# 2:   1 2000              8    1, 3, 6, 9, 12, 221   3
# 3:   1 2000              8    1, 3, 6, 9, 12, 221   6
# 4:   1 2000              8    1, 3, 6, 9, 12, 221   9
# 5:   1 2000              8    1, 3, 6, 9, 12, 221  12
# 6:   1 2000              8    1, 3, 6, 9, 12, 221 221
# 7:   2 2000             22              2, 3, 213   2
# 8:   2 2000             22              2, 3, 213   3
# 9:   2 2000             22              2, 3, 213 213
#10:   3 2000             32 3, 4, 12, 14, 213, 221   3
# ...

#now it is time to cretae a list of edges and vertices to build a graph with
# get edges (from >> to)
edges <- DT[!fid == V1, .(fid, V1)]
#    fid  V1
# 1:   1   3
# 2:   1   6
# 3:   1   9
# 4:   1  12
# 5:   1 221
# 6:   2   3
# 7:   2 213
# 8:   3   4
# 9:   3  12
#10:   3  14
# ...
vert <- DT[!duplicated(V1), .(fid = as.numeric(V1))]
vert[DT, value := i.violent_ev_sum, on = .(fid)]
#    fid value
# 1:   1     8
# 2:   3    32
# 3:   6     0
# 4:   9     2
# 5:  12     9
# 6: 221    NA
# ...

# with these objects, we can create a graph
g <- graph_from_data_frame(edges, directed = FALSE, vertices = vert)

# looks like
set.seed(123)
plot(g)
```

[image]

```
# or if you want the values of each vertex plotted:
V(g)$label <- vert$value
set.seed(123)
plot(g)
```

[image]

```
# to calculate the sum of neighbouring vertices,
# you have to loop over the vertices and get their `ego` network with a distance of 1
# see ?igraph::ego
# and sum the attributes of these neighboring vertices
ans <- data.table(fid = V(g)$name, 
           sum_neighbor = sapply( ego(g, 1 ,V(g), mode = 'all', mindist = 1), 
                                  function(i) sum(V(g)[i]$value, na.rm = TRUE)))
ans[order(as.numeric(fid)), ]
#    fid sum_neighbor
# 1:   1           43
# 2:   2           32
# 3:   3           46
# 4:   4          116
# 5:   5           18
# 6:   6           10
# 7:   7           69
# 8:   8           36
# 9:   9           31
#10:  10            0
# ...
```

Comment: I really appreciate the explanation following your code!

Comment: I added further observations to my data and found a way to avoid having the fid-variable listed in the neighbor_id-variable. However, if I rerun you solution I now receive: Error in graph_from_data_frame(edges, directed = FALSE, vertices = vert) :
Some vertex names in edge list are not listed in vertex data frame. Is there a way to fix this?